# JQgrid versus Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, kendo-ui

Can anyone tell me the basic differences between the Kendo UI Grid and the JQgrid?

Answer (score 6):

From my personal point of view the advantage of KendoUI over jqGrid + jQueryUI is that in Kendo UI you have most (all?) controls you need from a single source so it's actually pretty easy integrating them and they all look the same.

Controls from jQueryUI are pretty well integrated but then you need to go to jqGrid for grid, jXYZ for ... and not all of them support jQuery UI themes so the don't look the same. You end up having a site / application that doesn't look uniform.

Of course, these are my two cents and I agree that both are excellent grids.

Comment: Being able to use one library for all of our widgets was also the reason that my team went with KendoUI.

Comment: jqGrid integrates well with jQuery UI and looks the same... but you have a point for other jQuery plugins that may not integrate so well. If you are going to use jQuery UI you need to be particularly careful in this regard about choosing 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Both have a comparable set of features: Kendo UI grid seems a bit more polished overall in the demos whereas jqGrid has an extensive set of features (you could probably put together a feature matrix if you want to, but just compare the demos, there are so many more demo grids for jqGrid).

Kendo UI is not free, but includes an assortment of UI controls including a grid. On the other hand, jqGrid integrates nicely with jQuery UI and is free.

I also see there are ASP.NET MVC and JSP code samples for Kendo UI grid, whereas jqGrid includes ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET, and PHP server-side integration. But keep in mind since both are JavaScript controls, that you should be able to use any backend that you prefer. These controls just might make it easier out-of-the-gate.

I would base your choice on the other controls you are going to use in your application. If you are planning to make use of the other Kendo UI controls then you might as well go ahead and use the grid, too. Overall the Kendo UI controls demo very well so they may well be worth the price. But I have never used them...